# Using Regex to clean a csv file in R

Tags: regex, r, csv, data-cleaning

This is my first post so I hope it is clear enough.
I am having a problem regarding cleaning my CSV files before I can read them into R and have spent the entire day trying to find a solution.

My data is supposed to be in the form of two columns. The first column is a timestamp consisting of 10 digits and the second an ID consisting of 11 or 12 Letters and numbers (the first 6 are always numbers).

For example:

```
logger10    |
0821164100  |   010300033ADD
0821164523  |   010300033ADD
0821164531  |   010700EDDA0F0831102744
010700EDDA0F|
```

would become:

```
0821164100  |   010300033ADD
0821164523  |   010300033ADD
0821164531  |   010700EDDA0F
0831102744  |   010700EDDA0F
```

(please excuse the lines in the middle, that was my attempt at separating the columns...).

The csv file seems to occasionally be missing a comma which means that sometimes one row will end up like this:

```
0923120531,010300033ADD0925075301,010700EDD00A
```

My hardware also adds the word `logger10` (or whichever number logger this is) whenever it restarts which gives a similar problem e.g. `logger10logger100831102744`.

I think I have managed to solve the logger text problem (see code) but I am sure this could be improved. Also, I really don't want to delete any of the data.
My real trouble is making sure there is a line break in the right place after the ID and, if not, I would like to add one. I thought I could use regex for this but I'm having difficulty understanding it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my attempt:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.CSV") #list of each csv/logger file
for(i in temp){

    #clean each csv
    tmp<-readLines(i) #check each line in file

    tmp<-gsub("logger([0-9]{2})","",tmp) #remove logger text
    pattern <- ("[0-9]{10}\\,[0-9]{6}[A-Z,0-9]{5,6}") #regex pattern ??
    if (tmp!= pattern){ 
        #I have no idea where to start here... 
    }
}
```

here is some raw data:
logger01
0729131218,020700EE1961
0729131226,020700EE1961
0831103159,0203000316DB
0831103207,0203000316DB0831103253,010700EDE28C
0831103301,010700EDE28C
0831103522,010300029815
0831103636,010300029815
0831103657,020300029815

Comment: provide the actual input along with expected output. I didn't find looger text in your input.

Comment: What's wrong with replacing `(?:logger10)+\n*` with `\n` ?

Comment: post this in your question.

Comment: what's the actual delimiter `,` or `|` ?

Comment: its a comma, I wasn't sure how to space out the columns so it was more obvious

Comment: If you're expecting 10 characters always, you don't need regex. You just need `nchar()` and `substr()`. I would delete all commas and whitespace, and then any line with more than 20 characters gets fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately the ID varies between 11 and 12 characters so I'm not sure that would work?

Comment: No, if you cannot provide a 100% safe pattern for each entry, or at least a hint on when it must be 10, 11 or 12 symbols long, it is not possible to solve at this stage. Try fixing that before.

Comment: The time stamp is always 10 digits long but the ID is either 11 or 12 characters, depending on the individual the ID is attached to. The ID can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in a single pass:

```
(?:logger\d\d )?([\dA-F]{10}),?([\dA-F]{12}) ?
```

can be replaced with

```
\1\t\2\n
```

What this does is look for any of those rogue `logger01` entries (including the space after it) optionally: That trailing `?` after the group means that it can match 0 or 1 time: if it *does* match, it will. If it's not there, the match just keeps going anyway.

Following that, you look for (and capture) exactly 10 hex values (either digits or `A-F`). The `,?` means that if a comma exists, it will match, but it can match 0 or 1 time as well (making it optional).

Following that, look for (and capture) exactly 12 hex values. Finally, to get rid of any strange trailing spaces, the `?` (a space character followed by `?`) will optionally match the trailing space.

Your replacement will replace the first captured group (the 10 hex digits), add in a tab, replace the second captured group (the 12 hex digits), and then a newline.

You can see this in use on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cK1yB5/1) to see the results. You can use `code generator` on the left side of that page to get some preformatted PHP/Javascript/Python that you can just drop into a script.

If you're doing this from the command line, perl could be used:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:logger\d\d )?([\dA-F]{10}),?([\dA-F]{12}) ?/\1\t\2\n/g'
```

If another language, you may need to adapt it slightly to fit your needs.

**EDIT**

Re-reading the OP and comments, a slightly more rigid regex could be

```
(?:logger\d\d\ )?([\dA-F]{10}),?(\d{6}[\dA-F]{5,6})\ ?
```

I updated the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cK1yB5/2) link with the changes.

This still looks for the first 10 hex values, but now looks for exactly 6 digits, followed by 5-6 hex values, so the total number of characters matched is 11 or 12.

The replacement would be the same.

Comment: Could you please explain what this is: \1\t\2\n? and where it would go... sorry, I'm new to regex...

Comment: This is your replacement value. Some language, like Javascript, actually use `$1` instead of `\1`, but they are essentially the same. `\1\t\2\n` means that the replacement is supposed to only contain the first capture (the 10 hex digits), then a tab, then the 11-12 hex digits, and then a newline. You should be able to see the results of these on either of those regex101.com links provided (under SUBSTITUTION at the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Paste your regex here https://regex101.com/ to see whether it catches all cases. The 5 or 6 letters or digits could pose an issue as it may catch the first digit of the timestamp when the logger misses out a comma. Append an '\n' to the end of the tmp string should work provided the regex catches all cases.

Comment: You are right about the 5 or 6 digits... is there a way to check it backwards as there is always 10 digits in the timestamp?

Comment: Can you put the raw input into pastebin.com? There might be cases where both newlines and commas are missing and this needs to be handled.

Comment: Correcting the regex to 10 digits for the timestamp seems to work for now.  [0-9]{10}\\,[0-9]{6}[A-Z,0-9]{5,6}  Possibly a lookahead for the next instance to check its length and add the appropriate newlines.

Comment: Try this splitLine<-strsplit(tmp, " [0-9]{10}\\,[0-9]{6}[A-Z,0-9]{5,6} ", fixed=FALSE) and add each split line (whether it's 1 or 2 long) to a list. Loop through the list and write it to a new file with newlines added.

http://rfunction.com/archives/1499

Comment: My attempt at implementing @OnlineCop 's regex with R. The \t and \n should print tabs and newlines. Not

`tmp <-  "logger01 0729131218,020700EE1961 0729131226,020700EE1961 0831103159,0203000316DB 0831103207,0203000316DB0831103253,010700EDE28C 0831103301,010700EDE28C 0831103522,010300029815 0831103636,010300029815 0831103657,020300029815"  
tmp<-gsub("(?:logger\\d\\d\\ )?([\\dA-F]{10}),?(\\d{6}[\\dA-F]{5,6})\\ ?","\\1\\\t\\2\\\n",tmp, perl=TRUE) #remove logger text  
writeLines(tmp)  `

Comment: This looks really promising, thank you so much for your continued help. I'm not sure what writeLines() actually does? Is there a way I can create a two column data frame and store the values for tmp in there? I have tried creating an empty dataframe and rbind(df,tmp) but that didn't seem to do anything...

Comment: I tried writing the cleaned output to a CSV and then re-reading the cleaned CSV.
http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=j3hLjSaM&version=2